# PHP error after installation

Tags: install, php, setup

After I install craft, I am getting the following error when trying to load the website including the admin page:

```
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() \aspace\index.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() \aspace\index.php:14
PHP   3. CApplication->run() \aspace\craft\app\index.php:35
PHP   4. Craft\WebApp->processRequest() \aspace\craft\app\framework\base\CApplication.php:180
PHP   5. Craft\UserSessionService->requireLogin() \aspace\craft\app\etc\web\WebApp.php:272
PHP   6. CHttpRequest->redirect() \aspace\craft\app\services\UserSessionService.php:371
PHP   7. CApplication->end() \aspace\craft\app\framework\web\CHttpRequest.php:805
PHP   8. CApplication->handleError() \aspace\craft\app\framework\base\CApplication.php:0
PHP   9. CErrorHandler->handle() \aspace\craft\app\framework\base\CApplication.php:816
PHP  10. Craft\ErrorHandler->handleError() \aspace\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php:131
PHP  11. CErrorHandler->handleError() \aspace\craft\app\etc\errors\ErrorHandler.php:152
PHP  12. CErrorHandler->render() \aspace\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php:289
PHP  13. CWebApplication->runController() \aspace\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php:331
PHP  14. CController->run() \aspace\craft\app\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:282
PHP  15. CController->runActionWithFilters() \aspace\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php:265
PHP  16. CController->runAction() \aspace\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php:286
PHP  17. CInlineAction->runWithParams() \aspace\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php:308
PHP  18. Craft\TemplatesController->actionRenderError() \aspace\craft\app\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php:49
PHP  19. Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate() \aspace\craft\app\controllers\TemplatesController.php:190
PHP  20. Craft\TemplatesService->render() \aspace\craft\app\controllers\BaseController.php:98
PHP  21. Twig_Environment->render() \aspace\craft\app\services\TemplatesService.php:220
PHP  22. Twig_Environment->loadTemplate() \aspace\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:292
PHP  23. __TwigTemplate_d77269d0acd17023cd9970dd5812452d2a881ef03373e6e22c0d80eb68481e00->__construct() \aspace\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:345
PHP  24. Twig_Environment->loadTemplate() \aspace\craft\storage\runtime\compiled_templates\d7\72\69d0acd17023cd9970dd5812452d2a881ef03373e6e22c0d80eb68481e00.php:10
PHP  25. __TwigTemplate_9fccce442511366b01108e1e704c62f53125ce92b05eb6545ea02e38a06a15b3->__construct() \aspace\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:345
PHP  26. Twig_Environment->loadTemplate() \aspace\craft\storage\runtime\compiled_templates\9f\cc\ce442511366b01108e1e704c62f53125ce92b05eb6545ea02e38a06a15b3.php:10
PHP  27. Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass() \aspace\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:323
PHP  28. Craft\TemplateLoader->getCacheKey() \aspace\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:265
PHP  29. Craft\TemplateLoader->_findTemplate() \aspace\craft\app\etc\templating\twigextensions\TemplateLoader.php:71
PHP  30. Craft\TemplatesService->findTemplate() \aspace\craft\app\etc\templating\twigextensions\TemplateLoader.php:119
PHP  31. Craft\TemplatesService->_validateTemplateName() \aspace\craft\app\services\TemplatesService.php:835
PHP  32. Craft\PathHelper::ensurePathIsContained() \aspace\craft\app\services\TemplatesService.php:1178
PHP  33. Craft\HttpRequestService->decodePathInfo() \aspace\craft\app\helpers\PathHelper.php:29
PHP  34. Craft\StringHelper::convertToUTF8() \aspace\craft\app\services\HttpRequestService.php:1072
PHP  35. Craft\StringHelper::getEncoding() \aspace\craft\app\helpers\StringHelper.php:390
PHP  36. mb_detect_encoding() \aspace\craft\app\helpers\StringHelper.php:460
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was being caused because I was trying to access the server through 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: That's odd, but glad you got it sorted.  Craft should be more gracefully handling that situation, though. If you wouldn't mind helping to debug, could you send an email over to support@buildwithcraft.com so we can see what's going on?